# How to test ZF2 services

Tags: php, service, zend-framework2, phpunit

I wanted to test my services, which are called mostly by my controllers.
I implemented this :

```
  class FMaiAffaireServiceTest extends TestCase
    {
        public function setUp()
        {
            $this->myService = new FMaiAffaireService();
        }

        public function listAffairesCountTest()
        {
            $this->myService->listAffairesCount();
        }
    }
```

But PHPUnit doesn't recognize any test in here. How can I implement my little test please :) ? Thanks.

Here is my function (I didn't mentionned the database mocks intentionnaly)

```
class FMaiAffaireService
{
    public function __construct(
        FMaiAffaireTable $maiAffaireTable
    ) {
        $this->maiAffaireTable      = $maiAffaireTable;
    }

    public function listAffairesCount()
    {
        return $this->maiAffaireTable->listAffairesCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit will recognize any `public function` which name starts with `test` as a test. So instead of `listAffairesCountTest` your test needs to be named `testListAffairesCount`

https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html